# Free iOS app in Pending Contract

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I recently renewed my iOS developer membership and noticed that my free app, which has been available in the store for a year, is now in Pending Contract status. There is no information whatsoever of what conditions have changed and what I need to renew/enter/accept. Note that my app is free, so I shouldn't need to enter bank details, tax information, etc.

On the Agreements, Tax, and Banking page I can see that the "iOS Free Applications" contract has expired but there is no button to renew it. Has this type of contract been discontinued? Do I really have to enter my bank details and tax number even for a free app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26186854/1374538

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution:

My Apps -> Click on on the app -> Pricing

Choose the Price Tier and dates and Save.
The status of the app immediately changes from Pending Contract to Ready for Sale.

Still not clear why I had to redo it.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Whenever I try to update the pricing information and save it says , "error- nothing has changed."

Comment: This problem I worked around by changing Pricing to Paid, Tier 1, then Saved. Got a message like "you don't have any contracts blah-blah" which was OK since the app was free. Then changed it back to Free, Start Date=Now, End Date=None. Saved again. Bingo! The app is Ready for Sale.

Comment: hmm, wish it was that simple, i went through the same steps, but no joy :'(